# call python script function from other directory

Tags: python-2.7, function, relative-path

Trying to call function of a python script from some other directory.
Below is the simplified example:-

```
~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg $

pwd
/Users/mogli/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg $

ls
foo.py

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg $

cat foo.py
import sys

def hello():
    print('Hello :)')

def hii():
    print('Hii :)')

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg $

python -c 'from foo import *; hii()'
Hii :)

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport/eg $

cd ..

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport $

ls
eg

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport $

python -c 'from eg/foo import *; hii()'
  File "<string>", line 1
    from eg/foo import *; hii()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport $

python -c 'from eg.foo import *; hii()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named eg.foo

~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport $

python -c 'from eg.foo.py import *; hii()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named eg.foo.py
```

If execution directory is the same directory, where the python script is there, then below wroks
without any issue :-

> python -c 'from foo import *; hii()'

But if python script is in child directory, then below attempts didn't worked :-

> python -c 'from eg/foo import *; hii()'
>
> python -c 'from eg.foo import *; hii()'
>
> python -c 'from eg.foo.py import *; hii()'

python version on machine is 2.7.16

Comment: Why python has made simple import stuff from a relative path so complex? There are many Q on different portal and chain of complex solutions. In other C++, Java etc it is straight forward approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working... pyCall.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c "import sys;sys.path.append('./eg');import foo as foo1;foo1.hii()"
```

Run

> sudo chmod +x ./pyCall.sh
>   ./pyCall.sh

Make sure you have your foo file inside eg directory in this location.Did you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me->

```
python -c "from eg import foo as foo1;foo1.hi()"
Inside Eg Foo
python -c "import foo as foo;foo.hi()"
Inside First FOO
```

However, If you are using this inside scripts, You need to add you main path in path variables using below command.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Your main path")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named eg

Comment: eg is the directory where another foo code resides. Did you create that?

Comment: created a sample on github, https://github.com/moglideveloper/pyCall

Comment: Yes.. Correct code.. It is working for me.. Are u still facing challenge?

Comment: ~/playground/octagon/bucket/pythonImport $

sh pyCall.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named eg

Comment: ImportError: No module named eg

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you add this in your script. sys.path.append("Your main path"), Please provide absolute path.

Comment: Also, please check the unix access on file and folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python -c 'from ./eg/foo import *; hii()'`? Maybe all you need was the `./` at the start.

Comment: this would not work, cause it wouldn't be read as a `package`, please take a look at my answer